# PromQL and Grafana dashboard for nodes availability in cluster (status map?)

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Imagine that there are 10 nodes in cluster:

node1, node2, an so on..

I'm trying to write a PromQL query that checks existing metrics for ex. `up{instance=~"node.*"}` for last hour and check if metrics have stopped appearing at the current time for some nodes. It should tell me which nodes are up and which are down based on last 1h all nodes names.

Than I want to create on Grafana some kind of status map like this:

- node1: up (green square)
- node2: up (green square)
- node3: down (red square)

So query's result should be: node1: 1, node2: 1, node3: 0, ..

Any ideas?

Comment: What stops you? Query you have, panel to be used too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe only one thing you're missing is what kind of panel you should use.

You can achieve exactly what you need with the query you provided and Stat Visualisation:

[image]

Change thresholds and you're good to go:
[image]